User Control is so hard
I want to create a round button, and it works well at first.However, the control went wrong like this picture shows: (https://i.sstatic.net/AJNCYY98.png)
I asked chatGPT, and I followed his tips so compiler didn't warn but the control was nothing but a black squre, like this: (https://i.sstatic.net/CU8uoQfr.png)
My first source code is here:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RoundedButton : Button
{
    public int CornerRadius { get; set; } = 20;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
       
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddArc(0, 0, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
            path.AddArc(Width - CornerRadius, 0, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
            path.AddArc(Width - CornerRadius, Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
            path.AddArc(0, Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
            path.CloseFigure();

            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
        }

       
        TextRenderer.DrawText(pevent.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }
}


And there comes chatGPT's code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BookMs
{
    public partial class RoundButton : Button
    {
        private float radius;
        public RoundButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [Description("The radius of the arc.")]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public float CornerRadius
        {
            set
            {
                this.radius = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return this.radius;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CornerRadius <= 0) return; // 防止 CornerRadius 不合理的情况

            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                float diameter = CornerRadius * 2;
                // 确保 CornerRadius 不超过控件大小
                diameter = Math.Min(diameter, Math.Min(Width, Height));

                // 添加四个角的圆弧
                path.AddArc(0, 0, diameter, diameter, 180, 90);
                path.AddArc(Width - diameter, 0, diameter, diameter, 270, 90);
                path.AddArc(Width - diameter, Height - diameter, diameter, diameter, 0, 90);
                path.AddArc(0, Height - diameter, diameter, diameter, 90, 90);
                path.CloseFigure();

                this.Region = new Region(path);

                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
                }
            }

            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        }



    }
}


If it runs very well, we should see something like this:(https://i.sstatic.net/iVW1DGDj.png)

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that asking us to fix ChatGPT's code will probably not be well received here. Also your title is very uninformative.

Your first source code doesn't even have line 42 and there is a compile error.

Side note, you need to set e.Graphics.SmoothingMode =  SmoothingMode.AntiAlias before filling/drawing the path to smooth the rounded corners. You may also need to set e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half to fill in the borders correctly. No need if you're going to draw the borders e.Graphics.DrawPath yourself.

A clear problem is that you are disposing your path before you use it. Move the:
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
{
    pevent.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
}

inside the using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
With C# 8 and onwards you can avoid issues like this by using the using default scope which will dispose automatically at the end of the containing scope. In this case the method scope:
using GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
using SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor);

No curly braces required. "path" and "brush" will be disposed when the method scope ends.
